# a `let' binding is not available for subsequent `let' bindings?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I learn Emacs Lisp, because I want to customize my editor and to be clear I am little bit stuck with how Dynamic binding works.

Here is example:

```
(setq y 2)    

(let ((y 1)
      (z y))
  (list y z))

  ==> (1 2)
```

As a result I get back => **(1 2)**
Please could some one explain what actually going on. I tried to explain it for my self using concept of frames where each frame create local binding, but it seems like here it works in different way.

Why it doesn't take closest value of 'y' in the nearest frame?

If could describe in details what is going here, I will be so happy.

Thanks in advance. Nick.

Comment: I edited the question title. This has nothing particularly to do with dynamic bindings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In emacs lisp (as in many lisps), the values that will be bound in `let` are computed in parallel, in the environment "outside" the `let`.

As an example, the following is (approximately) equivalent:

```
(let ((a b)
      (b a))
  ...)

=>

(funcall (lambda (a b) ...) b a)
```

If you want to bind things in sequence, you should use `let*`, which does what you expected `let` to do.

Answer (score 3):

Your example seems to be taken straight from the [Emacs Lisp Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html). If you scroll down to `let*`, you'll get the explanation:

> This special form is like let, but it binds each variable right after
>   computing its local value, before computing the local value for the
>   next variable. Therefore, an expression in bindings can refer to the
>   preceding symbols bound in this let* form. Compare the following
>   example with the example above for let:

```
(setq y 2)
⇒ 2

(let* ((y 1)
       (z y))    ; Use the just-established value of y.
  (list y z))
⇒ (1 1)
```

Comment: yep, I did, I mean from Emacs Lisp Reference as a most straight forward one.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved if You use `let*` which allows You to use the `let`-mentioned vars:

```
(setq y 2)    

(let* ((y 1)
       (z y))
  (list y z))

  ==> (1 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of y you are setting in the let us only in effect in the BODY of the let, it is not yet in effect yet when you set z in the same let statement.